# How to retrieve values from 3d numpy array using multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I have a table of characteristics (3d numpy array) that has this shape:

```
characteristics = np.array((140, 401,9))
```

and have a final 1d array with 140 elements:

```
final_array = np.array(140)
```

Now, I have 3 conditions that I need to use in order to retrieve the characteristics and add them to the final_array.

1- Which elements in the first dimension from characteristics table will be added. Example:

```
which_elements = [True True False ... False True] # (140 elements)
```

So now we know that we will only use the characteristics of the first, second and last elements to add in the final array.

2- Each element in the characteristics array, is a (401x9) table, that we need to retrieve a single value by matching its row and column.
Example:

```
rows = [56 78 0 ... 0 43] # (140 elements)
```

meaning that for the first element, we retrieve the 56th row, second element 78th row, third element won't be used ... last element 43rd row.

```
columns = [8 7 0 ... 0 4]# (140 elements)
```

meaning that for the first element, we retrieve the 8th column, second element 7th column, third element won't be used ... last element 4th column.

Retrieving the right value, I will add them to the final_array.

I know how to do this iterating, search in the characteristics table element by element, but I need it to be a fast operation because it will be done more than a million times per second and I'm have difficulty doing this by boolean indexing in numpy. Any suggestions?

EDIT - TRYING TOMÁS VALLOTTON ANSWER:

```
import numpy as np

characteristics = np.array([[[500, 480], [480, 460]], [[460, 440], [440, 420]], [[420, 400], [400, 380]]])
print(characteristics)

final_array = np.zeros(3)

which = np.array([True, False, True])

rows = [0, 0, 1]
columns = [1, 0, 0]

expected_final_array = [480., 0., 400.]

# Tomás Valloton
array = np.where(which, characteristics[:, rows, columns], np.inf)
print(array[array != np.inf])

Output:
[480. 480. 440. 440. 400. 400.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help you?

```
array = np.where(which_elements, characteristics[:, row, columns], np.inf)
array[array != np.inf]
```

EDIT:

I suposed you didn't want the False elements. How about this?

```
array = np.where(which_elements, characteristics[:, row, columns], 0)
```

Comment: Hi Tomás, I tried an example of your answer and seems pretty close. Seems like the results are duplicated and also the middle element should be 0, sinze which is set to False. Will post the code in the question.

Comment: In this second attempt, the output is a 3x3 array. [[480   0 480] [440   0 440] [400   0 400]]. If I apply the following: array = array[:, 0]*[which][0] to your code, it will return the expected. Even though it gets the answer, can you merge it in your code, shortening, to get the 1d expected array?  By the way, thanks for the help.